# angular binding string into separate lines into html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an angular controller text file such as in the JSN

```
 topics: 'ab, bc, cd'
```

is being read into a td field .

However, it is a long string, but I am trying to cut the string and print each word into its own separate line. I tried creating a function which would cut the string and replace "," with a carriage return, but it still prints it into a single line. I tried also inserting \n or 
 directly within the string but it does not work either.

```
<td style=" background-color: green">{{data.topics}}</td>
```

The data is work data so I cannot post it but basically this is the gist of the idea.
So basically I would like to get into the cell

```
'ab'
'bc'
'cd'
```

as opposed to the entire string on one single line of the cell in that table.

Answer (score 2):

As long as topic is a property, why not do.

```
class SomeComponent implements OnInit{
    topics: Array<string>;
    constructor(service: MyService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        //not sure how your getting data
        this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
            this.topics = data.topics.split(',');
        });
    }
}
```

topics should now be an array. Then you can do ng-repeat.

```
<td style="background-color: green" *ngFor="topic of topics">{{topic}}</td>
```

Comment: thanks, so one question where should I put the $scope.topics piece inside the controller?

Comment: i'm not sure where you load your data, or what your controller looks like, but presumably where you can access the `data` object.

Comment: @JemiloII this question is tagged [tag:angular] not [tag:angularjs] not sure if it's miss tagged or you're using $scope for some other reason :)

Comment: iam trying your answer. will vote  as answer in a bit.thank you!

Comment: i get the data from a JS file, so I guess I do not need the subscribe service part